# C++ Struct packing order

Tags: c++, packing

I have a union that looks similar to the following:

```
typedef
union _thing
{
    struct thing_indiv {
        uint16_t one:5;
        uint16_t two:4;
        uint16_t three:5;
        uint16_t four:5;
        uint16_t five:6;
        uint16_t six:6;
        uint16_t seven:6;
        uint16_t eight:7;
        uint16_t nine:4;
        uint16_t ten:5;
        uint16_t eleven:6;
        uint16_t twelve:5;
        uint16_t thirteen:5;
        uint16_t fourteen:4;
        uint16_t fifteen:2;
        uint16_t unused:5;
    } __attribute__((packed)) thing_split;
    uint8_t thing_comb[10];
    
} thing;
```

But it doesn't behave how I expect. I want to assign bytes to `thing.thing_comb` and retrieve the relevant items from `thing.thing_split`.

For example, if `thing_comb = { 0xD6, 0x27, 0xAD, 0xB6. ..}` I would expect thing.thing_split.one to contain `0x1A` (the 5 most significant bits of `0xD6`, but it does not, it contains `0x16`, the 5 least significant bits. I declared each of the fields as `uint16_t` to keep gcc from complaining about crossing byte boundaries (I experience the same behavior with `uint8_t`).

Is there a way to lay out this struct to obtain this behavior?

Comment: `union` can't be used for type punning in C++.

Comment: *"crossing byte boundaries"*. You still have those `5+4+5 = 14`, `14 + 5 > 16`.

Comment: oh, alright. Is there another mechanism I can use to obtain this behavior or am I forced to use bitwise operators to do what I need?

Comment: bitfield is implementation specific, up to the compiler to use low, high (or mid) bit of underlying type.

Comment: Maybe this is related to big vs small endians, https://stackoverflow.com/q/105252/14273548

Answer (score 2):

First, type punning with an union in C++ is Undefined Behaviour.
Second, the Compiler is free to do anything it wants with a bitfield. It is not forced to lay it out like you want it to.

You need to use regular bit-packing with bitshifts to obtain the behaviour you want.

I had a similar question not so long ago:
[How to use bitfields that make up a sorting key without falling into UB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64414933/how-to-use-bitfields-that-make-up-a-sorting-key-without-falling-into-ub)

Comment: bit fields are implementation defined, which means the compiler must document it and then act according to that documented behavior. What you write rather sounds like unspeicified which is something different

Comment: Yes you are right. But the important part is that it is indeed dependent on the compiler and different compilers will yield different results. What works on one machine will not work on another compiler.

Comment: why quote a question when it has no answer?

Comment: "What works on one machine will not work on another machine." no, it means what works on one compiler will not work on a different compiler

Comment: @idclev463035818 the standard says that unions can only be accessed through the same member that they were created with.

Comment: @MarkRansom my complaint is about " Second, the Compiler is free to do anything it wants with a bitfield." which is about how bitfields are layed out in memory. Afaik this is implementation defined. Using it for type punning is the next step only

Comment: @MarkRansom ok, maybe I am reading something that the answer actually doesn't say. I'll shut up ;)

Comment: @idclev463035818 so the answer makes two points.  You're using one point to complain about the other.

Comment: @idclev463035818: *"why quote a question when it has no answer?"*. There is one now :-)

Comment: @Jarod42 thats a neat trick to advertise questions ;)